# The success and failure message is not displayed It always display some another error occurred though the data is inserted into database

Tags: php, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addDB.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&id=" + id + "&college=" + college + "&branch=" + branch + "&year=" + year + "&phone=" + phone + "&email=" + email + "&event=" + event,
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
        if (msg == 'error') {
            alert("Some error occurred");
        } else if (msg == 'exists') {
            alert("This email id is already registered.");
        } else if (msg == 'done') {
            alert("Registration Successfull");
        } else {
            alert("Some another error occurred");
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: add `console.log(msg)`.what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

You receive a success message but you are not converting your msg to a valid JSON object on the backend in addDB.php.

try this in addDB.php, wherever you define the "msg"

```
json_encode(['msg' => 'done']);
exit();
```